# Fetch Array data from API ReactJS

Tags: arrays, reactjs

i try fetch array data from a API with token, the problem is i fail to render/bind to display,every time debug will show error message like this. Please guide me, im new to react, this is my 1st app.
how to bind array to myadapater?
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzZrA.png)

here my code:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const url = " "; //api customer
const token = " "; //token

class Client extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: undefined,
      isLoaded: false,
      items: []
    };

    this.getData = this.getData.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
  }

  getData() {
    return fetch(url, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: "Bearer " + token
      }
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            items: result
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        }
      );
  }

  render() {
    const { error, isLoaded, items } = this.state;
    if (error) {
      return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          <p>data {items}</p>
          {items.map((items) => (
            <div>{items.name}</div>
          ))}
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}
export default Client;
```

Comment: Add code to your question, so others can understand it properly

Comment: remove the `{items}` part in your `render` method.

Comment: `<p>data {items}</p>` here you're trying to render an object

Comment: yes im trying but fail, here the error
fetch.then.then.setState.isLoaded
32 | .then((res) => res.json())
  33 | .then(
  34 |   (result) => {
> 35 |     this.setState({
     | ^  36 |       isLoaded: true,
  37 |       items: result,
  38 |     });

Answer (score 1):

There is only one real issue.

The use of `{items}` in the render method. If you want to display the actual JSON try `{JSON.stringify(items)}` instead.

Besides that i would also not use the same name in the `map`. So instead of `items` for the `map` function i would use `item` since you are dealing with one of the `items`.

```
    <div>
      <p>data {JSON.stringify(items)}</p>
      {items.map((item) => (
        <div>{item.name}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
```

---

Additionally, since you only use `getData` in the `componentDidMount` you do not need to bind it in the constructor (*that is required if you intent to pass that function to other component/functions outside of the current one*)

And you also do not need to `return` anything for the `getData` function since you handle the result in the `then` handlers.

So,

```js
class Client extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: undefined,
      isLoaded: false,
      items: []
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
  }

  getData() {
    fetch(url, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: "Bearer " + token
      }
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            items: result
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        }
      );
  }

  render() {
    const { error, isLoaded, items } = this.state;
    if (error) {
      return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          <p>data {JSON.stringify(items)}</p>
          {items.map((item) => (
            <div>{item.name}</div>
          ))}
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks @Gabriele Petrioli its work. Can it work for PUT & DELETE method too?

Comment: @Ali_Cradle sure.